# what does "echo 'PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc " do?

Tags: ubuntu, pipenv

I am following a list of commands in Ubuntu. I use Putty to connect to the server. I am not familiar with Ubuntu commands. Can someone tell me how it works?

```
echo 'PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc
pip3 install --user pipenv
. ~/.profile
pipenv install
```

I know 2nd and 4th lines. I have no idea about the first and third lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc
```

^ This adds ~/.local/bin to the PATH environment variable. This allows the user to run executables from this location without needing to type out the whole path.

```
pip3 install --user pipenv
```

^ This downloads a tool that helps create a python development environment.  I'm not too keen on pip and python.

```
. ~/.profile
```

^ This sources the file .profile from the user's home directory.  This likely contains additional environment variables (try running `env`).

```
pipenv install
```

^ This tells pipenv to set up your dev environment, I suppose.

Check out their github: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv